# how to print a div with a class on separate pages

Tags: javascript, css

I have divs with a particular class which I want to print on separate pages. I want to hide all the other stuff that's there like buttons, toolbars, etc. I would also like to apply some margin or padding at the top of each page. I am trying to do this with print stylesheets like following:

```
        @media print {
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body * {
            visibility: hidden;
        }
        .mydiv .mydiv * {
            visibility: visible;
        }
        .mydiv {
            padding-top:10em;
        }
    }
```

However, this leaves a big gap on the first page at the top, because there's other content and i guess setting visibility to hidden doesn't actually collapse the space that is being taken up by the other content that's there. I tried doing display:none and display:block for .mydiv, but nothing shows up on the pages. Also, on subsequent pages, mydiv has no margin at top and left. I tried the padding-top or margin-top I've tried em, mm, px, etc. but nothing seems to work.

Comment: you should use @media instead of @@media.

Comment: sorry this is asp.net razor syntax - the first @ is just to escape it.  I can assure you the stylesheets are having an effect. I've edited it here.

Comment: yes now code is correct.. this is the way of print view working

Comment: Can you please make simple reproducible example . It would help a lot to sort you issue if you can post a simple case which shows the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet, it should work for you

```js
window.print()
```

```css
@media print { 

    @page  
    { 
      size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */ 
      /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */ 
      margin: 0mm 0mm 0mm 0mm;  
    }
       
    body *:not(.mydiv) { 
      display:none
    }

    .mydiv * {
        display: block !important;
    }
        
    .mydiv {
      display: block !important;
      padding-top:0em;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title> New Document </title>
 </head>
<body>
  <h1 id="header">This should be hidden</h1>
  <div>This should be hidden too</div>
  <div class='mydiv'>
    <h1>This should be Printed</h1>
    <div> some other details that needs to visible in print </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but with this one I have to specify all the divs that I want to hide.

Comment: thanks I tried this approach already, but for some reason it just creates blank pages. Might be it's not supported on chrome yet.

Comment: I have tried it on chrome only and it works for me. https://i.imgur.com/mtvQcSe.png

Answer (score -1):

you can use page breaker. what page breaker do is, it will print all the content to the next page that you want to print.